# How can i use my component inside other modules in angular 10

Tags: angular

I need to use my sidebar component in my module in angular 10 but its throwing me a error while i use selector of component inside my module
'app-sidebar' is not a known element:
src/app/library/library-home/library-home.component.html:2:3 - error NG8001: 'app-sidebar' is not a known element:                                                                                                 1. If 'app-sidebar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.                                                                                                                           2. If 'app-sidebar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

what i did
first i export my sidebar component
exports: [SidebarComponent]

after inside my module
import {SidebarComponent} from '../sidebar/sidebar.component';

and putting in
imports: [SidebarComponent]

Comment: try adding @NgModule({schemas:[CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]]), also you can use shared module.

Answer (score 2):

Add to your `SidebarModule`:

```
exports: [SidebarComponent]
```

After that, import it to your `LibraryModule`. It should look something like this:

```
imports: [SidebarModule]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the component in your module, you have to declare it.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [SidebarComponent]
});
export class HomeModule {}
```

You don't need to export the component for it to work.